# What level can A pokemon go gym reach?

Tags: pokemon-go

I understand how the gyms work with battling friendly gyms to raise the gyms level. Just wondered if anybody knows if there is a cap to the level it can reach? I presumed it would be level 6, but I've seen level 7 gyms around.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Level 10:
10 Pokemon/50k Prestige
Currently have a 2109 Lapras in a level 10 gym.